# How do I go back in Visual Studio's Properties window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on Visual Studio and was checking the properties for a file, when I accidentally double-clicked one of the properties and now the window is completely blank. Captures below for clarity:

[Properties window showing the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTzyK.png)
[What happened after I double clicked one of the property names.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts71E.png)

I've tried clicking everywhere, right click options don't fix it. Restarting Visual Studio also didn't fix the issue. I looked into VS docs but found nothing. So far the only option I've been given is to reset the IDE to default settings but I'd rather not do that. I just want to understand *where* I landed, *why* and *how* to get back.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Select your program.cs file

Comment: Your screenshots show files of two different types?  Is one entire file type broken, or just the one file / one project?

Comment: Actually, I'm suspecting that your double-click opened a JSON configuration file for the IDE (VS Code absolutely loves these, full Visual Studio not quite as much, but it's trying to be compatible with VS Code which means it too now has JSON configuration).  When you close that (which closing Visual Studio **does not do**, since it remembers open files), and put focus back in your .cs file, you'll get back the original properties.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring out what the issue was. I had double-clicked the "Build Action" Title, which switches its value to the next in the dropdown. It was initially "None" and it got switched to "Page"

[Build Action dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCPYx.png)

I don't know why VS is like this, but if you select "Page", the properties dissappear, which doesn't let you switch it back to "None" or whatever else.

[CSProj file ItemGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYfbo.png)

To get back my properties I just had to go to the `.csproj` file and edit it manually back to "None". With that I got my properties options back.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a little old but I faced the same issue but was able to solve it differently, in my case, what I did was:

- Select the option 'Show All Files' on Solution Explorer.
- Right-click on the file > 'Exclude From Project' option.
- Right-click again > 'Include In Project'.

By doing that the Build Action was restored to 'C# compiler' and nothing was lost.